# Space complexity of bubble sort algorithm

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

i am trying to do a study on Space complexity of bubble sort algorithm what i know that the Space complexity of bubble sort algorithm is O(1) given the below bubble sort algorithm how can i change the bubble sort aalgorthim code to make the space or memory complexity to O(n) or O(n square) , etc i need to understand where the space complexity playes a role ...thanks

```
 public void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;

    while (swapped) {

        swapped = false;
        j++;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your algorithm already is `O(n)` space. Note that `O(1)` is a *subset* of `O(n)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space complexity is a measure of how much extra memory your algorithm requires.

If you were to allocate an extra array of size n (when n is the variable size of the input array), the space complexity would be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to increase space complexity you just need to waste memory e.g. add some code to use more memory.

Its decreasing space complexity which is hard.

Comment: code means instructions in the algorithms or should i increase the data ? thanks man

Comment: You shouldn't increase memory usage except if it improves performance and you need that improvement, or in this case, for interest sake. If you want to increase memory usage as O(N) add `arr.clone()` at the start. or for O(N^2) you can add inside the first loop. For O(N^3) add it inside the nested loop.

Comment: To be exact, to increase space complexity (with big O notation) you don't need to do anything. O(1) is a subset of O(n). For big-Theta notation, the answer is perfectly fine, of course.

Answer (score 6):

I think it worths an answer, because it has some input on big O notation:

**Your algorithm already is `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` space**

This is because `O(1)` is a subset of `O(n)` and both are subsets of `O(n^2)`

Why is it so?

Note that `O(f(n))` is a set of functions with "asymptotic upper bound of f(n)" (intuitive definition, not formal).

Thus, for each `g(n)<h(n)<f(n)`, if `h(n)` is an asymptotic upper bound of `g(n)`, then f(n) is also asymptotic upper bound of it.

Thus, if `g(n)` is in `O(h(n))` - it is also in `O(f(n))`

And in your case, if the complexity function `T(n)` is in `O(1)`, it is also in `O(n)`

Answer (score 5):

Your algorithm already is O(n) space, since you need at least n cells of memory

Comment: No, her algorithm doesn't require any "extra" memory and the sorting takes place in the same unsorted array! So according to my understanding, it's O(1) wrt space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Here space complexity of your algorithm is O(n) and Auxiliary Space complexity it O(1).

In general we do compare Auxiliary complexity. why ?

Merge-Sort takes O(n) auxiliary space and Insertion sort requires O(1) auxiliary space Space complexity of these two sorting algorithms is O(n) though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bubble sort(A,n)
  for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
     for(j=1;j<=i-1;j++)
       if(a[j]>a[j+1])
       {
         t <- a[j]
         a[j] <- a[j+1]
         a[j+1] <- t
       }
```

Here we show input variable and temporary variable for space complexity then i and j are input variable of which space complexity always be constant and temporary variable t always be show 1 so space complexity of bubble sort is o(1).

Answer (score 0):

In general sorting algorithms have space complexity O(1). This is a good thing

How to waste more memory would be if you would copy your input to another array. The time complexity is the same, you only add O(N), but now, you need O(n) memory because you need to allocate space for each position.

For example, for heapsort, you require to build a heap. In this case you need to use more memory.

Comment: You can't build a heap in place?

Comment: @Cruncher You can, but for heapsort you need to pop it and add it to the front of the array. The easiest way to do this is using a little extra memory.

Comment: "In general sorting algorithms have space complexity O(1).". Why? quick sort is not O(1) (it is O(logn) for the stack). merge sort is O(n).

Comment: @amit There are O(1) implementations for quicksort and mergesort, but you are right about standard implementations, those are also good examples of requiring more than O(1) memory.